# breakpoint already hit 1 time

Tags: gdb, breakpoint

I'm following Erickson 2008 Hacking the art of exploitation. The program is very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main() {

char str_a[20];
strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
printf(str_a); 
}
```

I set a break at line 6

```
(gdb)break 6
(gdb)break strcpy
```

...which prompts

```
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y 
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb) break 8
```

Then I should be able to step through the program. With run or start and cont. However the program skips the break point 2. "info breakpoints" says breakpoint already hit 1 time at start. How do I make GDB stop at breakpoints even after being reached once? I thought this was the answer.

```
enable -- Enable all or some breakpoints.
enable breakpoints -- Enable all or some breakpoints.
enable breakpoints count -- Enable some breakpoints for COUNT hits.
enable breakpoints delete -- Enable some breakpoints and delete when hit.
enable breakpoints once -- Enable some breakpoints for one hit.
enable count -- Enable some breakpoints for COUNT hits.
```

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
I'll keep digging trying to find the solution but for now it seems a mystery.

Edit:
I believe the problem lies in gdb disabling my breakpoint at start. When I start the program, it disables breakpoint 2, then I run enable 2 check info breakpoints, and it's enabled, but it never stops there. I changed the addresses and "What" column for formatting.

```
Num     Type                 Disp Enb  Address          What.      .         .
1       breakpoint             keep y   0x0005 in main at **7.
        breakpoint already hit 1 time.                                .               .
2       STT_GNU_IFUNC resolver keep y   0x0007 <strcpy_ifunc>.        .      .
3       breakpoint             keep y   0x0005 in main at **8. 
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output looks like this

```
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00005555554006c1 in main at x.c:6
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x00007ffff7a7f980 in strcpy_ifunc at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/ifunc-unaligned-ssse3.h:33
```

This means that only breakpoint 1 - the one for line 6 has been hit once. Not the one for `strcpy`